# Scrapy - parse a page to extract items - then follow and store item url contents

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a question on how to do this thing in scrapy. I have a spider that crawls for listing pages of items. 
Every time a listing page is found, with items, there's the parse_item() callback that is called for extracting items data, and yielding items. So far so good, everything works great.

But each item, has among other data, an url, with more details on that item. I want to follow that url and store in another item field (url_contents) the fetched contents of that item's url.

And I'm not sure how to organize code to achieve that, since the two links (listings link, and one particular item link) are followed differently, with callbacks called at different times, but I have to correlate them in the same item processing.

My code so far looks like this:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "example.com"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.example.com/?q=example",
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('example\.com', 'start='), deny=('sort='), restrict_xpaths = '//div[@class="pagination"]'), callback='parse_item'),
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('item\/detail', )), follow = False),
    )


    def parse_item(self, response):
        main_selector = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        xpath = '//h2[@class="title"]'

        sub_selectors = main_selector.select(xpath)

        for sel in sub_selectors:
            item = ExampleItem()
            l = ExampleLoader(item = item, selector = sel)
            l.add_xpath('title', 'a[@title]/@title')
            ......
            yield l.load_item()
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After some testing and thinking, I found this solution that works for me.
The idea is to use just the first rule, that gives you listings of items, and also, very important, add follow=True to that rule.

And in parse_item() you have to yield a request instead of an item, but after you load the item. The request is to item detail url. And you have to send the loaded item to that request callback. You do your job with the response, and there is where you yield the item.

So the finish of parse_item() will look like this:

```
itemloaded = l.load_item()

# fill url contents
url = sel.select(item_url_xpath).extract()[0]
request = Request(url, callback = lambda r: self.parse_url_contents(r))
request.meta['item'] = itemloaded

yield request
```

And then parse_url_contents() will look like this:

```
def parse_url_contents(self, response):
    item = response.request.meta['item']
    item['url_contents'] = response.body
    yield item
```

If anyone has another (better) approach, let us know.

Stefan

Comment: That's how I do it. I think the only other alternative is to regroup the data at the stage of storing/outputting.

Comment: Yes, we've got also confirmation on scrapy group, so I've chosen my answer

Answer (score 2):

I'm sitting with exactly the same problem, and from the fact that no-one has answered your question for 2 days I take it that the only solution is to follow that URL manually, from within your `parse_item` function.

I'm new to Scrapy, so I wouldn't attempt it with that (although I'm sure it's possible), but my solution will be to use `urllib` and BeatifulSoup to load the second page manually, extract that information myself, and save it as part of the Item. Yes, much more trouble than Scrapy makes normal parsing, but it should get the job done with the least hassle.